# Ruling out NHiberate mappings causing deletion of entity

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I have an NHibernate issue where I update an entity and it causes the deletion of another entity. The set of entities and related mappings is too large to replicate here but I wanted to create some sample data in order to discuss the issue. In this cut out example imagine updating **D** results in the deletion of **A**.

**Q:** Is it fair to say that it is ***impossible*** for this to be a mapping issue given all mapping files related to **A** ie (BMappingFile & CMappingFile) have their mapping to **A** set as ***.Cascade.None()*** or is there some other NHib config/mapping related setting that I should be aware of that could achieve this behaviour?

**DB tables**

**A**

Aid **|** Aname

**B**

Bid **|** Bname **|** Aid

**C**

Cid **|** Cname **|** Aid

**D**

Did **|** Dname **|** Cid

and a set of corresponding mapping files along the lines of

**AMappingFile**

```
public AMap()
{
    Table("[dbo].[A]");
    LazyLoad();
    Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();

    Id(x=>x.Aid)
    .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
    .Column("[Aid]")
    .GeneratedBy.Identity();

HasMany(x=>x.Bs)
    .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
    .Fetch.Select()
    .Inverse()
    .LazyLoad()
    .KeyColumns.Add("[Aid]")
    .Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();

HasMany(x=>x.Cs)
    .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
    .Fetch.Select()
    .Inverse()
    .LazyLoad()
    .KeyColumns.Add("[Aid]")
    .Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();

    ...
}
```

**BMappingFile**

```
public BMap()
{
    Table("[dbo].[B]");
    LazyLoad();
    Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();

    Id(x=>x.Bid)
    .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
    .Column("[Bid]")
    .GeneratedBy.Identity();

    References(x=>x.A)
    .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
    .Cascade.None()
    .Fetch.Select()
    .Columns("[Aid]");

    ...
}
```

**CMappingFile**

```
public CMap()
{
    Table("[dbo].[C]");
    LazyLoad();
    Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();

    Id(x=>x.Cid)
    .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
    .Column("[Cid]")
    .GeneratedBy.Identity();

    References(x=>x.A)
    .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
    .Cascade.None()
    .Fetch.Select()
    .Columns("[Aid]");

HasMany(x=>x.Ds)
    .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
    .Fetch.Select()
    .Inverse()
    .LazyLoad()
    .KeyColumns.Add("[Did]")
    .Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();

    ...
}
```

**DMappingFile**

```
public DMap()
{
    Table("[dbo].[D]");
    LazyLoad();
    Cache.ReadWrite().IncludeAll();

    Id(x=>x.Did)
    .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
    .Column("[Did]")
    .GeneratedBy.Identity();

    References(x=>x.C)
    .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
    .Cascade.None()
    .Fetch.Select()
    .Columns("[Cid]");

    ...
}
```

Comment: What code do you use to modify and save these objects?

Comment: It could be any class of update to any entity in the object graph. There are no deletes occurring. I'm more interested in confirming that if the direct mapping files to A are all Cascade.None() that I can rule out the mappings and hopefully gain a suggestion as to what else could be at play.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide snippet of your code or queries but back to your question.

> I have an NHibernate issue where I update an entity and it causes the deletion of another entity

Suppose you persisted `A`-entity instance with collection of 5 `B`. Once you would update instance of `A` using empty collection of `Bs` all `B`s would be removed.